# Phpunit, how to mock an abstract class?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

Im talking about this function:

```
function testMeSomehow ($id, Flag $flags)
{
    $flags::NAME;
}
```

its parameter object:

```
abstract class Flag
{
    abstract function method1();
    abstract function method2();
.
.
.
    abstract function method999();
}
```

how to mock this `Flag` class? It has tons of abstract methods, should I create all of them with empty body? And what if this class changes? I also have to add a `NAME` constant to it

Comment: What if you try first? Why do you think mocking an abstract class is something different from mocking an ordinary class or an interface?

Comment: thats right, but see that $flags::NAME ? How to set a constants for the mock?

Answer (score 2):

You can mock it with test doubles like you would do for any other class, see https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

This could be an example test:

```
class TargetClass
{
    public function testMeSomehow($id, Flag $flag)
    {
        return $flag->method1();
    }
}

class TargetClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('Flag');
        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('method1')
            ->willReturn('methodResult');

        $targetClass = new TargetClass();
        $this->assertEquals('methodResult', $classToTest->testMeSomehow(1, $mock));
    }
}
```

You can specify the methods that you want to replace by the mock as the 2nd parameter of `$this->getMock()`. Because we don't specify anything at all, it will replace all methods and thus won't bother about the abstract methods.

Edit: added an example to access constants:

```
class ClassToTest
{
    public function testMeSomehow($id, Flag $flag)
    {
        return $flag::NAME;
    }
}

class FlagTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testStuff()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('Flag');
        $classToTest = new ClassToTest();
        $this->assertEquals('Flag name', $classToTest->testMeSomehow(1, $mock));
    }
}
```

If you want a specific value for that constant in your tests, I suggest to make a child class with this constant and use that for mocking.

Edit: added an example with a workaround to specify dynamic constant values.

```
class Flag
{
    const NAME = 'Flag name';

    public function getName()
    {
        return static::NAME;
    }
}

class TargetClass
{
    public function testMeSomehow($id, Flag $flag)
    {
        return $flag->getName();
    }
}

class TargetClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('Flag');
        $mock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getName')
            ->willReturn('New flag name');

        $targetClass = new TargetClass();
        $this->assertEquals('New flag name', $classToTest->testMeSomehow(1, $mock));
    }
}
```

However, this compels you to use the `getName()` method everywhere, so I personally prefer the previous suggestion: mocking a child class that has the changed value.

Comment: I added an example to access the constant, this code works for me.

Comment: It is not possible to change constant values on the fly. I added a workaround if you really want to specify a lot of different values for different tests, but I would go with the previous solution.